# How often would you tolerate your IDE crashing?

Tags: ide

I was experimentally trying to switch from coding in vim to coding in an IDE (in this case, Anjuta on Linux), but I found that every time I crashed the IDE, my trust in it went down, until around a crash rate of once a day I trusted it so little that using it was considerably more stressful than using a simple text editor for coding.

How often would your IDE have to crash, fail, or do completely unexpected things before you would stop trusting it enough to use it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with all the new-fangled goodness (3.5, WPF, LINQ, ...) and especially the WPF designer (which sucks anyways) crashes every other day. While this is truly annoying I've not had any mayor data loss and I try to workaround it by not using the WPF designer (which -- have I mentioned it yet? -- does suck anyways).

I think it's not a matter of *trust* but whether the IDE (or any kind of software) really does bring enough functionality to the table to be worth the annoyance? That's a pretty personal value judgement and for me it means: Studio, yes; WPF designer, no. Pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

For me once a day is too often.

Also I think this question is borderline not relevant.

**Edit:** BTW I primarily do Python programming at the moment and I don't use an IDE, just a text editor with multiple commandlines open.

Comment: Thank you; I will aim to improve my relevance in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a lot of the beta and CTP releases of Visual Studio over the years and since these are unfinished softwares, I couldn't expect them to run stable.

In this scenario, it's important to offer a good backup strategy. Recent versions of Visual Studio allow you to save changes even for projects that are just temporary, i.e. that you've not given a name.

Unfortunately, when you start the IDE anew after a crash, Visual Studio erases all temporary projects. I can see why they do it but it's a very poor decision in terms of crash recoverability.

Other than that, I'm really intolerant when it comes to crashes. This is one reason why I could never work with Eclipse. The IDE has too many arbitrary bugs for my taste and it really drives me nuts.

Nowadays, I mostly use (G)VIM/mvim and there's hardly ever any crash.

Answer (score 0):

In a word - "never".

The only time ever I use an IDE is when I'm writing code for Android.  Other than that, I use gvim and command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

I swear under my breath every time Visual Studio 2003 crashes but I seem to be able to tolerate it...

Answer (score 0):

I use IntelliJ IDEA and it rarely crashes on me.  If it crashed more than, say, once a month I'd be looking elsewhere and/or screaming loudly at support.

At least on Intellij, it saves your work for you automatically and does local versioning so you rarely lose anything from a crash (I've never lost more work that can be measured in minutes) plus if you make a horrible mess of something you can recover an older working version easily, which I like a lot as it doesn't pollute the "common" repository with frequent check-ins that don't necessarily compile let alone work just to make sure you have a rollback position.